# Indentation oops with "if condition then <a> else <span>" in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indentation, slim-lang

I have to render either an  or a  depending on a condition, however, slim's indentation and "no explicit end allowed" gets in the way.

In this simplified code, I'd like to wrap a product with three DIVs in either an A or a SPAN depending on whether the product is available or not.

---

```
- if available?
  a href=...
- else
  span class="unavailable"
.currency = @product.currency
.price = @product.price
.description = @product.description
```

The above obviously won't work since the product is not rendered within the A or SPAN but next to it.

---

```
- if available?
  a href=...
- else
  span class="unavailable"
  .currency = @product.currency
  .price = @product.price
  .description = @product.description
```

This case is even worse, because slim treats the product as part of the "else" case and renders the product next to the SPAN and not at all for the A.

---

```
- if available?
  a href=...
- else
  span class="unavailable"
    .currency = @product.currency
    .price = @product.price
    .description = @product.description
```

Here everything is fine for the SPAN but the A remains empty because the product is treated as part of the "else" case.

---

```
- if available?
  a href=...
- else
  span class="unavailable"
- end
  .currency = @product.currency
  .price = @product.price
  .description = @product.description
```

Now, this could be correct, but slim doesn't allow explicit "end" and therefore raises an exception.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

PS: Maybe slim should allow explicit "end" for edge cases like this one.

Comment: I guess that a way you can go about this is to create a partial to hold the product, and then render same from both sides of your conditional. so, `- if available? a href=... (render product) - else span class="unavailable" (render product)`  Hope you get the idea, as I can't seem to get good formatting with comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I could come up with as a workaround:

Using [capturing to local variables](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Capturing_to_local_variables) you save your children in a local variable:

```
= capture_to_local children=:children
  .currency = @product.currency
  .price = @product.price
  .description = @product.description
```

And now you can run

```
- if available?
  a href=...
    = children
- else
  span class="unavailable"
    = children
```

I don't have slim set up, just tried it with haml, but it should work just the same :)

Comment: It won't win a beauty-prize, but it's a good enough workaround. However, since it's a Rails app, I've used the `capture` instead. Thanks for the inspiration!